# Giving users permission to see files, but not open them in Windows server 2008 R2

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, permissions, network-share

I was wondering if any of you know how to make a folder that will give normal users in a domain access to the the files located in the folder, and access to add files, but not access to open the files.

The purpose of this is that I have a technician that don't have access to other users files (he shouldn't either), but this technician is in charge of moving files from a secure zone to a insecure zone. So the purpose is that the users will instead add files to this folder, and the technician will have full access to this. But the users adding the files in the folder, should not be able to open the other users files.

This is on a Windows Server 2008 R2. 
I have tried messing around with the advanced permissions, without hope. The closest i came, was that the users were able to add files in the folder, but they couldn't see them afterwards, which will make alot of confusion if the files is in the folder or not.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want to set a temporal directory in which users can add their own files but not open the files of other users (apart from the technician that will have full access to that folder).

In that case take a look to this blog post from [Raymond Chen](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/) that explains how to do something very similar:

[How do I create a directory where people can create subdirectories but cannot mess with those created by other users?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20160524-00/?p=93515)

Although the title mention subdirectories it also applies to files:

> But let's suppose that the customer's "not overwrite existing content" really means "not overwrite existing content created by other users". In other words, we want to let users create new content, and they can do whatever they want to the content they created, but they can't mess with content created by others.

The article also notes that the system temp directory `%windir%temp` is configured in a similar way, maybe you should take a look at its permissions because I think that configuration is very close to what you want (see the permissions of `Users` and `CREATOR OWNER`, in your case you would need also the permission `List folder contents` for `Users`).

Finally, note that this prevents users to open/modify files from other users but they can still *see all the files* in the folder.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible with NTFS permissions.  List Folder/Read Data is a combined permission.  If you need them to see them afterwards (like your last sentence suggests), then just not possible.

You could potentially do something with each user having their own folder (no different than a home dir) that the tech has rights to, but that moves away from the scope of your question.

Comment: You can set the List Folder/Read Data permission to apply to the folder only and _not_ files within the folder. Then rely on the users' CREATOR OWNER permission on their own files to provide them with read access.

Answer (score 0):

You could try EFS (NTFS encryption) but you need to always keep the files on NTFS for it to work. Only the user would have access to the files. Or maybe you could script the move that the Tech is performing and use a service account that the tech doesn't know.